# Somo question about Monodevelop addin

Tags: mono, monodevelop

i'm a .NET programmer who prefer to.. use Linux as main system. 
Beaside this, i would like to know

1. if exists a **CSS auto completion** add in for MonoDevelop
2. if exists something to reformat html code like the **CTRL+ALT+K** in Visual Studio

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) I've not tried it, but Miguel de Icaza has recently pointed out a JS/CSS add-in: http://junalmeida.github.com/JsCssEditor/

2) Alt+Shift+F is bound to "Format Document" (at least in MD 2.8). It works on XML and claims to have worked on HTML pages (all of the lines go from unchanged to changed) but unless it is good XHTML then I think it currently fails to do anything useful.